# Name of the host machine of an iPhone/iPad simulator

Tags: ios-simulator

I need to know a name of the host machine for a iPhone/iPad Simulator. My guess is it should be possible but I was not able to find the way yet. Why do I need it? This is because [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] returns the same name "iPhone Simulator" for any simulator running on the same network. And I need to work with a particular one located on the Mac with name "My Mac Dev Machine". An application that runs on the simulators should be able to determine that is runs on "My Mac Dev Machine"'s simulator and should allow the connection from the network. Any ideas?

Comment: For those who are interested in solution to this problem. I have solved it with an IP address. Instead of obtaining a name of the simulator’s host machine, I am getting the device’s IP address and show my application in the network like "<IP address>/iPhone Simulator". It allows distinguishing several iPhone Simulators in the network and selecting the correct one to connect with.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and was able to use uname() within the simulator to get the host's node name, like so:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#endif
```

...

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
- (NSString *)testProxyHeaderValue {
    struct utsname name = {};
    uname(&name);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"iPhone Simulator @ %s", name.nodename];
}
#else
- (NSString *)testProxyHeaderValue {
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
}
#endif
```

The simulator's node name is the same as the host's node name, which can be obtained with `uname -n` on the command-line.

In Swift 2:

```
var name = utsname()
uname(&name)
return withUnsafePointer(&name.nodename) {
    String.fromCString(UnsafePointer($0))!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I've you're dealing with a simulator/emulator, isn't it logical that whatever is being simulated has absolutely no idea that it's simulated?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It will be great if iPhone Simulator allow to configure a unique name for the simulator. It would solve the problem. But unfortunately it is not the case. So, this makes a simulator different from a device. If I know name of the host machine, I can assign a kind of "unique" name for the simulator.